# FooPlot "oneboxing"

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

"[Oneboxing](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting)" is a great way to share content quickly in chat. It would be awesome if it would work with [FooPlot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XjIrOHgrMTUiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItMzguMzE3NDU1MTY4MjY5MjU1IiwiNDYuMDAyNTQ0ODMxNzMwNzYiLCItMTcuOTkwODkwNTI3MzQzNzQ0IiwiMjIuNjQ5MTA5NDcyNjU2MjUzIl19XQ--) (an online graphing calculator), that way we could share graphs in the Math SE site without having to screen shot, crop, and upload it. It would also be helpful if this could be implemented for asking questions, maybe how MathJax works. I'm sure it would be useful for the Physics site, too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, oneboxing use screenscraping to analyze the remote content - the FooPlot is using HTML5 graphics which can't really be screen scraped, so they have to first build some sort of API. That said, I would be glad to stand corrected.

Comment: The canvas is HTML5? I remember using it in 4.

Comment: @DantheMan then you must be quite impressive; [MDC lists `<canvas>` as "Introduced in HTML5"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/canvas). EDIT: perhaps a better link is [the "new elements" section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements) of the W3C's _HTML5 differences from HTML4_ doc.

Comment: @PopularDemand WebKit introduced `<canvas>` in 2004, Gecko in 2005, and Opera in 2006.

Comment: @YannisRizos mmm, "standards."